# Get values from multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript

I have an array from which I want to get only names.

```
var peoples = [
  { "name": "dod", "class": "a", "age": 12 },
  { "name": "john", "class": "b", "age": 14  },
  { "name": "henry", "class": "c", "age": 23 }
];
```

How can I get the name from each object with comma separation?

Comment: `peoples.map( function(v){ return v.name; }).join()`

Comment: peoples[0].name Use a for-loop to iterate them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jquery,

```
var peoples = [
  { "name": "dod", "class": "a", "age": 12 },
  { "name": "john", "class": "b", "age": 14  },
  { "name": "henry", "class": "c", "age": 23 }
];

var names = new Array();
$.each(peoples,function(key,value){
    names[key] = value.name;
});
namelist = names.join(",");
console.log(namelist);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9344Q/

Comment: few comments `var names = new Array(); => var names = []` and `names.join(",") => names.join()` as default join charactor is `,`

Comment: I don't know, question not asked about `jQuery` solution and answer is `jQuery` based .. there good solution for this in native js .. instead of loading heavy JavaScript library

Comment: @rab In most cases, web sites will have jQuery, So it doesn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely do it in plain Javascript:

```
var peoples = [
  { "name": "dod", "class": "a", "age": 12 },
  { "name": "john", "class": "b", "age": 14  },
  { "name": "henry", "class": "c", "age": 23 }
];

var arr = [];
peoples.forEach(function(name) {
    arr.push(name['name']);
});

console.log(arr.join(','));
```

Comment: as `Array.prototype.forEach` is part of `Ecmasript 5`, it better to use `Array.prototype.map` for this .

Answer (score 0):

```
var peoples = [
  { "name": "dod", "class": "a", "age": 12 },
  { "name": "john", "class": "b", "age": 14  },
  { "name": "henry", "class": "c", "age": 23 }
];
alert(peoples.map( function(v){ return v.name; }).join());
```